# Converting Tensorflow Code to PyTorch by Removing Placeholders

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I know that placeholders in Tensorflow are used to define a variable which will have data assigned to it later on, but they cannot be directly evaluated.
I was trying to convert the following code to PyTorch: CVAE/model.py at master · jaechanglim/CVAE · GitHub
In the code they define placeholders like this:

```
self.X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, [self.batch_size, None])
self.Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, [self.batch_size, None])
self.C = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, self.num_prop])
self.L = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32, [self.batch_size])
```

These placeholders are used before data is assigned to them such as here:

```
weights = tf.sequence_mask(self.L, tf.shape(self.X)[1])
```

Then data is finally assigned to them such as here:

```
X = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embedding_encode, self.X)
```

I have read that you pass tensors directly to modules in PyTorch and placeholders are not used, but what exactly does this mean? Also, what changes would I make to this to convert it into PyTorch so that I don’t declare a placeholder for self.X, but am able to still use it?

Comment: there are many implementations of CVAE in TF2, which is far more similar to pytorch, why are you so interested in this one?

Comment: You should go through a tutorial on basic PyTorch https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/deep_learning_60min_blitz.html